# Reused Metal Groan in Video Games

Tags: reused, effect, video-games, metal

I've been noticing this sound being used quite a bit mainly in video games, and I'm just curious if anyone knows where its from, it's obviously from a library.

Doom 3 (@ 0:36):

[youtube]quS52KtB8Kw[/youtube]

Bioshock (@ 6:36):

[youtube]ZgDEh3UN404[/youtube]

Battlefield 3 (@ 1:07):

[youtube]ac3uinK0jM8[/youtube]

I think I've even heard it when watching gameplay footage of Dead Space but I haven't played the game so I'm not entirely sure, I think it was when a necromorph was breaking down a fence or something.

Answer (score 2):

always funny to see different sound effects editors discover the same sound.

I know that early in my career I thought that I was being **very** creative and original when I'd find a great library sound that worked perfectly in a given moment, then feel sick to my stomach when I'd hear that same effect cut in by someone else in a similar spot on a completely different project.  There's a kid laugh that's in every kid spot, and a certain set of doors that run rampant through otherwise very good TV shows (looking at you Mad Men and Dexter)

I think the rise of the microlibraries is mitigating that somewhat, but some of the more popular ones will inevitably become widely adopted enough that a few of us will "discover" the same gems independently even in those.

we can't always record all of our sound effects, but I think games have more latitude to do so because they're dealing with longer timelines and deeper levels of integration.

(I'm assuming that the point of the post is to show that people are using the same effect, not to request its location so that you can use it too.)

Comment: Ive heard that 'kids laughing' sound EVERYWHERE!!

Comment: @Rene Right, although I would like to know where it's from just out of curiosity not to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the library it is from but it sure sounds like a [waterphone](http://www.waterphone.com/) or water instrument, possibly by Richard Waters.  However, I am listening on my laptop speakers right now.  Check the link

Answer (score 0):

Thats cool that you linked them all up, definitely sounds like the same sound.  Not sure what library it comes from but you could make that sound yourself quite easily with a metal bin and scraping something sharp over it slowly giving a metal groan sound.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure I've seen it in a library under 'Metal Gate creaks and groans'. Probably from a Sound Ideas library. In any case, I'll now be avoiding it should it pop up, or including it as the creaky metal equivalent of the Wilhelm scream